# How to Read parquet file using apache arrow in cpp from cloud storage S3

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

the aws path where parquet file is stored will look something like:
/aws/default/...

I have tried using #include <arrow/filesystem/s3fs.h> but couldnt figure out the exact methods of this library which can be used.

```
 // Open the Parquet file for reading
arrow::fs::FileSelector file_selector(s3_path);
arrow::Result<std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::InputStream>> input_stream_result = s3fs->OpenInputStream(file_selector);
```

Comment: How did you construct `s3fs`? Does `s3_path` contain your bucket name?

Comment: From the Python documentation it looks as simple as `BUCKET_NAME/path/within/bucket`.